# Why URL-alias of taxonomy doesn't have the correct language, is this a bug?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, path-aliases, i18n-l10n

I have a multisite (drupal 7) with Pathauto and my vocabulary is set to '*Translate. Different terms will be allowed for each language and they can be translated.*'

I add a taxonomy term in **English** with pathauto enabled but when I check the URL-alias for this taxonomy it says:

[image]

Is this normal? I want it to be English too. Pathauto does this correct for a node but not for a taxonomy term.

[edit] When I create the alias manually the problem remains. So the problem isn't PathAuto.